# Button inside RecyclerView item doesn't register clicks sometimes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView list that displays an item which houses some TextViews and Buttons. I have already linked the buttons of each item to a specific function. The fragment looks like this.

[image: recyclerview fragment]

The two buttons (Red and Blue) changes its function based on the user's status. e.g. when a user is not approved, the blue button will show "Activate Account" and the red button will show "Remove Request", each with their own function. All the functions of the button work as intended, but there is a slight problem. When I click on one of the two buttons, it sometimes won't register the click. I think it might have to do with the RecyclerView's scrolling property. Is there any way to overcome this problem? I want those buttons to function as normal buttons that when the buttons are touched, it will always register as a button click, not a recyclerview drag.

**RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
class AccountViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView text_name;
    TextView text_username;
    TextView text_status1; // Approved | Pending
    TextView text_status2; // Admin
    TextView text_status3; // Operator
    Button button_left; // Deactivate | Remove Request
    Button button_right; // Admin | Activate
    private WeakReference<AccountListClickListener> listenerRef;

    public AccountViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, AccountListClickListener clickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        listenerRef = new WeakReference<>(clickListener);

        text_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_name);
        text_username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_username);
        text_status1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_status);
        text_status2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_status2);
        text_status3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.acc_status3);
        button_left = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_left);
        button_right = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_right);

        button_left.setOnClickListener(this);
        button_right.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == button_left.getId())
            listenerRef.get().leftButtonClick(getAdapterPosition(), button_left.getText().toString(), text_username.getText().toString().substring(10));

        if (view.getId() == button_right.getId())
            listenerRef.get().rightButtonClick(getAdapterPosition(), button_right.getText().toString(), text_username.getText().toString().substring(10));

    }

}

public void setFilter(int i){
    this.statusFilter = i;
}
```

}

**RecyclerView Fragment**

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<Account> accountList;
private AccountAdapter accountAdapter;
private Timer timer;
private View view;
private boolean isActive;
private RadioGroup rg1, rg2;
private int filter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    isActive = true;
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.view = view;

    accountList = new ArrayList<>();

    rg1 = view.findViewById(R.id.fg_acc1);
    rg2 = view.findViewById(R.id.fg_acc2);

    rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(isActive) {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).populateAccountCards();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }, 0, 100);

    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("account");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()){
                accountList.add(snap.getValue(Account.class));
            }
            accountAdapter = new AccountAdapter(view.getContext(), accountList, new AccountAdapter.AccountListClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void leftButtonClick(int i, String button, String username) {
                    switch(button){
                        case "DEACTIVATE ACCOUNT":
                            modifyAccount(ref, 0, username);
                            break;
                        case "REMOVE REQUEST":
                            modifyAccount(ref, 1, username);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void rightButtonClick(int i, String button, String username) {
                    switch(button){
                        case "REMOVE AS ADMIN":
                            modifyAccount(ref, 2, username);
                            break;
                        case "MAKE ADMIN":
                            modifyAccount(ref, 3, username);
                            break;
                        case "ACTIVATE ACCOUNT":
                            modifyAccount(ref, 4, username);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));



            recyclerView.setAdapter(accountAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

public AccountAdapter getAccountAdapter(){
    return this.accountAdapter;
}

/*
0 - Deactivate Account
1 - Remove Account
2 - Remove as Admin
3 - Make Admin
4 - Activate Account
 */
private void modifyAccount(DatabaseReference ref, final int i, final String user) {
    final Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    DatabaseUtil.readDataByUsername(user, ref, new OnGetDataListener() {
        @Override
        public void dataRetrieved(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener1 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child("activated").setValue(false);
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child("admin").setValue(false);
                                    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder1.setMessage("Deactivate Account of " + user + "?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener1)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener1).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener2 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder2.setMessage("Delete Account of " + user + "?\nWARNING: ALL DATA WILL BE LOST").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener2)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener2).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener3 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child("admin").setValue(false);
                                    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder3.setMessage("Remove Admin Access of " + user + "?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener3)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener3).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener4 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child("admin").setValue(true);
                                    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder4 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder4.setMessage("Grant Admin Access to " + user + "?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener4)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener4).show();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener5 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    dataSnapshot.getRef().child("activated").setValue(true);
                                    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                    break;

                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Action Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder5 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder5.setMessage("Activate Account of " + user + "?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener5)
                            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener5).show();
                    break;

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void dataExists(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Apparently I have a timer thread that runs at a fixed interval which calls a function to populate the cards and filter the items based on the radiobutton filter selected. The timer executes that function every 100 milliseconds that updates the item adapter, which doesn't give the system enough time to register the button press. **Changing the timer interval to a longer duration solved the problem.**

It made sense as when I touch the button for more than 100 milliseconds, the system wouldn't recognize that I touched the original button anymore because it already populated a new set of viewholders and ultimately, the button I was touching was now gone, along with its onclick function.